# Neo4j Serialization of the data as JSON

Tags: node.js, rest, serialization, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to build a rest api with Node.js which uses [Neo4j-Bolt-Driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver) to connect to Neo4j-Db.

As the endpoints and the complexity of the graph grows, it is getting a lot harder to write and maintain a lot of long Cypher queries.

I'm having some difficulties to serve populated JSON objects which should contain some relations to the other nodes.

Below you see the query for a for GET /api/me endpoint.

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.uuid = {userId}
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:PROFILE_IMAGE]->(profileImage:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HEADER_IMAGE]->(headerImage:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:OWNS]->(productToEmbed:Product)-[:TYPE]->(productType:ProductType)
WITH user, COLLECT(productToEmbed{.*, type: productType.name }) AS products
RETURN user{.*, products: products, profileImage: profileImage{.*}, headerImage: headerImage{.*}}
```

It gets even worse when the node which is connected to the user can have different labels. In that case; I should write a switch case expression in the cypher query to correctly populate related fields which doesn't feel right.

Any suggestions about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you can do is use pattern comprehension to take care of the optional match and collect in a single step. Just a small syntactical improvement.

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.uuid = {userId}
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:PROFILE_IMAGE]->(profileImage:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HEADER_IMAGE]->(headerImage:Image)
WITH user, profileImage, headerImage, 
 [(user)-[:OWNS]->(productToEmbed:Product)-[:TYPE]->(productType:ProductType) | 
 productToEmbed {.*, type: productType.name}] as products
RETURN user{.*, products, profileImage, headerImage}
```

As for the other nodes with different labels and fields, can you provide an example?